# Разделитель между двумя контролами

Tags: java, android, separator

Видел в некоторых приложениях `Separator` (разделитель между двумя вьюшками, который можно двигать). Но не могу найти, с помощью какого `activity` это можно реализовать у себя в программе.

**Добавил:**

У меня есть два фрагмента: слева находится лист, справа - пользовательский фрагмент. Сейчас задана константная ширина для левого фрагмента-листа. Хочу сделать вертикальный сепаратор между ними. При этом на вид на телефоне это никак не должно отразиться, только для планшета.

Comment: Сепаратор в какой вьюшке? Если в меню это одно, если в ListView другое, если горизонтальная/вертикальная линия тоже другое... Уточние

Comment: @Barmaley, обновил.

Comment: Так что, в этом случае нужно просто добавлять панель между этими фрагментами и обрабатывать события мыши? То есть готового решения нет?